# Submit Form to New Window/Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, new-window

I've wrote a simple 'add page' form to a small CMS I've built and I have a simple preview feature which submits a form and opens the front-end version of the page in a new window.

To achieve this up until now I've used:

```
<input type="submit" name="pagepreview" value="Preview" formtarget="_blank">
```

Apparently the formtarget which made this possible is depreciated (which I never actually knew) and it seems that Google may have removed this feature in their latest update as it's stopped working (but still works in Firefox).

What's my alternative here? The answers I've found all point back to formtarget or target but neither work any longer.

Ideally I'd want to avoid Javascript but if that isn't possible - how would I submit the form to a new window using Javascript or jQuery?

**EDIT:**

Apologies for not explaining well enough - I can't add the target attribute to the form as only one button allows a new window (the preview button) the others just submit on the same page. Javascript appears to be my only way to do this.

Comment: and changing formtarget to target?

Comment: @Fincha - I get the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: "Apparently the formtarget which made this possible is depreciated (which I never actually knew) " — It isn't.

Comment: @Quentin - Oh, a quick Google led me to believe otherwise hence my assumption about Google maybe removing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="..." method="..." target="_blank">
   <input type="submit" name="pagepreview" value="Preview">
</form>
```

If you need to change the target dynamically:

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $form = $this.parents('form');
    $form.attr('target',$this.attr('formtarget'));
    $form.get(0).submit();
    event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: The JS here was very very close. I had to change line 6 to `$('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');` If you update your answer, I'll accept as correct.

Comment: Strange, triggering click event in click handling function? I don't understand that. I don't see the whole picture maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a system that is probably quite hard to visualise without knowing it the way I do. Your answer really put me on the right track though and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

like this: (add `target = "_blank"`)

```
<form action="" method="" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" />
</form>
```